# Linking error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, linker, arduino

I followed the instructions to setup Eclipse IDE to work with my Arduino UNO board from here: http://www.chipkin.com/articles/using-eclipse-with-arduino-duemilanove

I successfully compiled the core library except a warning for the tone.h file. When I try to compile a blinky project which uses the arduino library, it is throwing me linking errors. I have spend my last day trying to figure out the problem but with no success. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Edit:** Now I successfully created a 'Template' project following instructions from here:

> http://www.chipkin.com/articles/using-eclipse-with-arduino-duemilanove

But the problem is when I try to build a project which is a copy 'Template' project, compiler will start throwing linking errors. If I try to compile the same code from 'Template' project, it will compile fine. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the references are correct for your workspace? I had some issues using Eclipse templates for Arduino as the compiler threw up a lot of errors/warning due to various path issues.

I've literally just gotten the blink example and arduino core library build working on my Uno. I could zip and link if you want? Might shed some light on where you're going wrong.